# box-shadow with different size on sides

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with borders on all sides using `box-shadow` CSS property.
currently the thickness of the shadow was 5px on all sides.But i need these borders with thickness 5px on top and bottom,10 px on left and right sides.

I know is possible to do this using `border-left,boder-right,border-top,border-bottom`.
But i need find a solution to use `box-shadow`  only.

Is it possible?

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple `box-shadow` values.

```
div {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px #888888,
              inset -10px 0px 0px #888888,
              inset 0 5px 0px #888888,
              inset 0 -5px 0px #888888;
}
```

Change the x and y factor to increase / decrease the thickness of shadow (border) on each side.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px #888888,inset -10px 0px 0px #888888, inset 0 5px 0px #888888, inset 0 -5px 0px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I shold have posted before I went for coffee... :) ... upvoted yours, deleted mine

Comment: @LGSon I had plans for upvoting yours and I'll if you will undelete :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using multiple, comma-separated value definitions:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0px 0px #888888, inset -20px 0px 0px 0px #ff0000, inset 0px -15px 0px 0px #00ff00, inset 20px 0px 0px 0px #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 5px #888888,inset -10px 0px 0px 5px #888888
}
```